# Simple animation in react-native: moving an image from left to right

Tags: react-native, animation

Can anyone share a code example for a react-native animation that moves an image from left to right, then move back to the starting point and repeat the motion?

#### Update:

The answer below helped a lot, but it didn't work. I used it to create the following animation that moves an image from left to right (I am using RN 0.62.2).

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Animated, Easing } from 'react-native';

const test = require('../images/test.png');

export class Splash extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { xValue: new Animated.Value(-100) }
    }

  moveLR = () => {
        Animated.timing(
          this.state.xValue,
          {
            toValue: 100,
            duration: 1000, // the duration of the animation
            easing: Easing.linear, // the style of animation
            useNativeDriver: true
          }
        ).start();
  }

  moveRL = () => {
    Animated.timing(
      this.state.xValue,
      {
        toValue: -100,
        duration: 3000, // the duration of the animation
        easing: Easing.linear, // the style of animation
        useNativeDriver: true
      }
    ).start();
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.moveLR();
  }

  render = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Animated.Image
            style={{ width: 170, height: 146 }}
            source={test}
            style={{ width: 170, height: 146,
                transform: [{ translateX: this.state.xValue }] }}>
        </Animated.Image>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  animationView: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update by Yossi:

The code below didn't work for me in RN 0.62.2. I am accepting the answer, but I modified it and the code that is working is included now in the question.

#### Original answer:

Before getting started, I need to introduce you to the two types of values ​​for Animated animations:

Animated.Value () where we define a value, useful when we want to move an element on a single axis (X or Y), change the size of an element, etc. This is what we will use here, in this chapter, and this is what is used the most.

Animated.ValueXY () where we define a vector, useful for moving an element on two axes.

With these values, we can define several types of Animated animations. We will discover them one by one, testing them each time. in this example, I will only talk about Animated.timing ()
Here you can see an example of code which is gonna moove a red box from left to right and stop when the user decides, you can try it and tell if it worked for you :

```
// Test.js


import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Animated, TouchableOpacity, Text, Easing } from 'react-native'

class Test extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    leftPosition : new Animated.Value (0)
  }
  this.mooveLR = this.mooveLR.bind(this);
  this.mooveRL = this.mooveRL.bind(this);
  this.stopAnimation = this.stopAnimation.bind(this);
}
  
 stopAnimation  () {
    this.setState({
      leftPosition : this.state.leftPosition // this forces the left position to remain the same considering the `componentDidMount` method already happened
    })
  }

  mooveLR (){
    Animated.timing(
      this.state.leftPosition,
      {
        toValue: 100,
        duration: 3000, // the duration of the animation
        easing: Easing.linear, // the style of animation 
      }
    ).start() // starts this annimation once this method is called
  }
  
  mooveRL (){
    Animated.timing(
      this.state.leftPosition,
      {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 3000, // the duration of the animation
        easing: Easing.linear, // the style of animation 
      }
    ).start() // starts this annimation once this method is called
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    this.state.leftPosition === 0 ? this.mooveLR () : this.mooveRL () // repeats always when the red box return to its initial position : leftPosition === 0
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.animation_view, {left : this.state.leftPosition}]}>
        
        </Animated.View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = { () => this.stopAnimation ()}>
          <Text>Stop animation</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main_container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  animation_view: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  }
})

export default Test;
```

Hope it's gonna help
Regards

Comment: You are welcom sir

Answer (score 1):

Since I prefer using react hooks, I converted the solution Provided by @pacy.eth, and here it is for anyone who prefers to use react hooks.

```
import { View, Text, Animated, Easing } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Animate= ({ children, left, leftP, duration }) => {
  const [leftPosition, setLeftPosition] = useState(new Animated.Value (leftP));

  useEffect(() => {
    left ? mooveLR() : mooveRL();
  }, []);

  const mooveLR = () => {
    Animated.timing(leftPosition, {
      toValue: 100,
      duration, // the duration of the animation
      easing: Easing.linear, // the style of animation
    }).start(); // starts this annimation once this method is called
  };

  const mooveRL = () => {
    Animated.timing(leftPosition, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration, // the duration of the animation
      easing: Easing.linear, // the style of animation
    }).start(); // starts this annimation once this method is called
  };

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[{ left: leftPosition }]}>{children}</Animated.View>
  );
};

export default Animate;
```

And with a little modifications, I made it reusable in severals ways:

one of my favorite ways, is by wrapping the component that I want to animate and I pass the the direction "**left: true or false**" I set the "**leftP**" which is the leftPosition (in my case I am hiding the view and with a click of a button I slide it in with the Animate component created) and the "**duration**" of the animation.

for ex:

```
<Animate left={false} duration={1000} leftP={-Dimensions.get('window').width}>
...
</Animate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by doing:

```
import {
  Easing
} from 'react-native';
```